# How to assign variable value to our ng-options value of select tag in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have this `select` tag below:

```
  <td class="style126">
    <select id="CountrySelect" name="country" class="form-control" style="width:42%;height:100%" ng-model="selectedCountry" required ng-options="Country as      Country.CountryName for Country in countries| orderBy:countryOrderProp">
      <option value="">--------Select--------</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td class="style126">
    <select id="departmentSelect" name="department" class="form-control" style="width:42%;height:100%" ng-model="selectedDepartment" required data-ng- change="updateDepartment()" ng-options="Department as Department.DeptName for          Department in Departments | orderBy:departmentOrderProp">
      <option value="">--------Select--------</option>
    </select>
  </td>
```

I'm trying to assign value to `ngModel` using `$stateParams`. How can I achieve this?

My `$stateParams` are:

```
$scope.course = $stateParams.course;
$scope.selectedCountry = $stateParams.country;
$scope.selectedDepartment= $stateParams.Deptname;
```

Comment: `console.log($stateParams.Deptname);` what prints?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting values from `$stateParams`?

Comment: yes , $stateParams.deptname==rrrr

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-options is

```
Department as Department.DeptName for Department in Departments
```

That means that you want each option value to be the department itself (i.e. the object), but to be displayed as the department's name. So to be clear, when you select a department from this select box, the `selectedDepartment` will be assigned with the whole department object. Not with its name.

The corollary is that if you want to preselect a department from a state parameter containing the department name, you needs to find the department object, among the array of departments, that has the given name, and assign this department object to `selectedDepartment`.

Or you can choose to change the ng-options to

```
Department.DeptName for Department in Departments
```

Then when selecting a department, `selectedDepartment`  will be set to the name of the selected department. And you can thus assign a department name to `selectedDepartment` to pre-select it.